# Extremely slow internet speeds and Wifi adpadter isnt detected when i use lspci

Tags: wireless

Basically the title. I just downloaded Linux. and my internet speeds are terribly slow. I'm using an HP Pavilion 2000-365dx. I'm pretty sure its a broadcom card. but I'm really not sure and not incredibly techy, I would apperciate it if someone could help me. I just got ubuntu. Thanks in advance

```
lspci -nn
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)

06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

I've got a screen shot for the other one

[image]

also, now I'm connected to the internet but it says the connection speed is `6 mbp/s` and on windows I got 54.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t), type `lspci -nn`, and add the output to the question. You might also add the output of `sudo lshw -C network`.

Answer (score 0):

Install **Wicd Network manager**:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk wicd wicd-daemon wicd-curses wicd-cli
```